# Do people with Asperger's tend to be more conservative?

Tags: parties, ideology, conservatism

I myself have Asperger's syndrome. I'd like to know is there any Democrats who has Asperger's? All my friends I've talked to people/my friends who have Asperger's they are all Republican and so am I. So I'm kind of curious if any one who is a Democrat has Asperger's. I've personally never met someone who is/identifies.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to ask this on psychology SE instead? It's probably okay here too... but I suspect you'll get more opinion-based rather than research-based answers here.

Comment: Comments deleted. Comments on questions [should be used to suggest constructive criticism for the question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Please don't use comments to answer the question. If you would like to answer, post a real answer which adheres to our quality standards.

Comment: I think that while the question in the title is fine, the text in the main question should probably be edited to be less opinion-based.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps.

There are lots of people with Asperger's syndrome/Autism/ASD that identify strongly with the left and strongly with the right.  There are also many who are politically neutral, or who are strongly anti-political. Examples

- ["Left-leaning democrat"](https://www.dailykos.com/stories/2015/5/31/1389425/-My-Asperger-s-my-Politics)
- ["Conservative party member"](http://www.oneinfive.scot/aspergers-syndrome-and-politics/)
- [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/aspergers/comments/3ej952/aspergers_and_political_views_what_do_you/) in which people who identify as aspies describe their political views

There is a study "Empathy and Political Preferences", which finds a relationship.

> More empathic individuals are more likely to identify with and vote for parties of the
> left.

One trait of people with Asperger's is a reduced ability to empathise with others (compared with a neurotypical baseline) the implication of this finding is that there would be a relationship between a measure of empathy and political identification:

> > [image]
>
> More empathetic people were more likely to vote for the Liberal or New Democrat parties (centre-left and left) than for the conservative party (right wing)

There is some evidence that, while people with Asperger's can be highly committed, either to the right or the left, they are less likely to successfully enter politics. The selection and election mechanisms tend to favour neurotypical candidates.

One feature of Asperger's syndrome is a reduced ability to "see the world from another person's point of view", and a tendency towards "black and white" thinking. This can make it hard for a person with Aspergers to find validity in a person having differing political points of view.

Comment: Do you have a reference to show that developed (rather than adolescent) individuals have a tendency towards "black and white" thinking?  False dichotomies are often claimed when people try to reason ideas logically, but with maturity comes the ability to recognize that multiple categories influences events.  And since separate chains of causalities exist in each category, this leads even the most logic-grounded thinking into considering how much weight each of the categories has on subjects of discussion.  But, again, this comes with maturity. Does Asperger's prevent this maturation?

Comment: Yes, it was in one of the sites I linked at the top.  Also https://www.aspergerrus.com/what-is-asperger-syndrome.html  Just as neurotypicals can develop the problem-solving and perfectionist traits that are typical for Asperger's,  Aspergers can develop their flexible thinking skills. But what comes naturally for aspies, can be hard work for NT and vice-versa.

Comment: Your second to last paragraph is a masterpiece of politely and carefully saying that us aspies ***bloody well suck at convincing people***.

Comment: This answer just fits so well. I have no idea if I am on the spectrum at all (I've been told I might be), but this answer is so very good. I have a theory about the last paragraph. Its off topic but related to conceptual leaps that require assumptions or blind faith.

Comment: what is NDP? Libertarian?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Democratic_Party

Comment: I am an Asperger and consider myself opposed to conservative views.

Comment: Re: empathy When I Googled "Autism empathy", the first results were https://leader.pubs.asha.org/doi/10.1044/leader.FTR2.25042020.58 https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/people-with-autism-can-read-emotions-feel-empathy1/ https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/women-autism-spectrum-disorder/202006/can-i-have-empathy-if-i-am-autistic https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6794557/ etc. There's also https://www.jneurosci.org/content/early/2020/11/09/JNEUROSCI.1237-20.2020 Maybe you should engage in more due diligence before posting negative claims about marginalized groups?

Comment: I suspect that there isn't good direct data and that political participation generally is lower among people with Asperger's syndrome.